# Is High Frame Rate (HFR) being used for films apart from The Hobbit?

Tags: film-techniques

Are there any films coming out in [High Frame Rate (HFR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_frame_rate)?

I can't seem to find anything about the use of HFR except commentary on The Hobbit. Is this technology considered for broader use in the film industry and gaining traction since it's debut in the Hobbit series or is it considered somehwat of a "failed experiment"?

Or are there any studios openly working on fixing the issues with HFR, maybe in conjunction with a feature film release? (I'm talking about adapting make-up, costume, props etc.)

Comment: This seems very "list-y".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_frame_rate#Usage_in_the_film_industry

Comment: Yeah I checked Wikipedia before I posted this. But, is that *it*? I would have expected more than one or two filmmakers to be having a go.

Comment: it's expensive and filmgoers seem to hate it.

Comment: It's always possible to convert 30fps movie to 60fps. It's not completely the same, but you might enjoy it.

Comment: I tried to rephrase the question into a less list-based format, to accomodate for the "too broad" close-votes it started to attract. I think in its current form as a broader analysis of HFR's reception in the film industry it works quite well.

Comment: @Lettmannen Films don't get shown in 30 fps... they're generally shown in 24 FPS... HFR is 48 (animation may be as low as 12-15 FPS). TV is technically 60 half frames per second, or 30 FPS... this is due to video. Creating fake frames to "upgrade" 24 FPS to 48 PFS looks really crappy because blurring is really bad. It's just not a good idea.

Comment: I know much about fps and i am familiar with the process of making fake 60fps as you call it. The results show some visual artifacts, but i wouldn't say anything about blurring. I don't see it being that bad. Anyway, this is off-topic, my apologies.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_with_high_frame_rates

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any films coming out in High Frame Rate (HFR)?

Yes.

James Cameron [has said](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/james-cameron-fully-intends-make-172916) that he'll be using **HFR** for his Avatar sequels.

> Cameron revealed that he considered shooting Avatar at 48 fps, but decided the time wasn’t right.  However, he intends to shoot Avatar 2 and 3 at a higher frame rate - the question is whether that  will be at 48 or 60. He is currently writing the script and is at least 18 months away from starting to shoot.

[Source: Hollywood Reporter's Comic Con coverage.](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/james-cameron-urges-industry-use-173577)

Andy Serkis [has said](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/andy-serkis-animal-farm-381314) the same about his film adaptation of George Orwell's book "Animal Farm."

> Noting that he worked with "an extraordinarily talented crew and an amazing array of talent" on The Hobbit, Serkis now is exploring the use of some of the tools and techniques used to bring Middle Earth to the screen, including 3D and high-frame-rate photography and projection.

Comment: Can you please include the quotes in your answer? Right now, it's more of a "your answer is in another castle" answer.

Comment: @Catija Added quotes and sources.